# google map display error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-maps-api-3

hi i have working on google map application i have already apikey and also followed all the steps given in [android developer](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) but when i run the project it shows white grid screen but not shows the map on my emulator

Answer (score 1):

Check this link for [MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=instantiation%20exception%20in%20google%20Maps%20in%20Android) . Also ensure that you have generated your API key correctly as per the Documentation. Check you have generated MD5 fingerprint of the debug keystore correctlt in its location.

For generating API key check this [link](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)..

Also check you have included

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in Manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, I regenerated api key and it worked immediately.